# Jekyll: after clicking on a specific category and going to a new page, it shows no posts with that category while I have some that fit

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

My website has a categories page that lists all of the categories for you to click on, which redirects you to a page with all the posts that fit that category. However, despite having posts with categories, none are showing up.

This is in my config file:

```
    scope:
      path: categories
    values:
      location: Category
      breadcrumb:
        -
          label: Home
          url: /
        -
          label: Categories
          url: /tabs/categories/
  -
```

and it worked with tags.

This is my layout file:

```
---
layout: page
---

{% include date-format.html %}

<div id="page-category">
  <h1 class="pl-lg-2">
    <i class="far fa-folder-open fa-fw text-muted"></i>
    {{ page.title }}
    <span class="lead text-muted pl-2">{{ site.categories[page.category] | size }}</span>
  </h1>

  <ul class="post-content pl-0">
    {% for post in site.categories[page.category] %}
    <li class="d-flex justify-content-between pl-md-3 pr-md-3">
      <a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      <span class="dash flex-grow-1"></span>
      <span class="text-muted small">{{ post.date | date: POST_DATE }}</span>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my index.html file in /categories/blogging/:

```
---
layout: category
categories: [Blogging]
title: "Blogging"
---
```

I would really appreciate some help.